# I created a button in storyboard, and set the image programmatically, and I am getting an error, why?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I created a button in storyboard and linked it to my custom class, but when I set the image, and run the program I get a nil error.

[image]

```
func getCurrentUserProfilePic(){

    let propicquery = PFUser.query
    propicquery()!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        var object = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId
        for object in objects!{
            let userPic = object["ProPic"] as! PFFile
            userPic.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if(error == nil){
                    let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                    self.userpic = UIButton()
                    self.userpic.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
                    self.userpic.addTarget(self, action: "userchange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
                    self.userpic.layer.cornerRadius = self.userpic.frame.size.width / 2;
                    self.userpic.clipsToBounds = true
                    self.view.addSubview(self.userpic)
                }

            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: once check for the instance of self.userpic button while setting the image

Comment: The updated code works, but it picks up the wrong image. Why, I set the object equal to the current user id, but it picks up the wrong image.

Comment: but no where you mentioned to fetch the users with the current userId, your query don't have any predicate to fetch the user with the current userId...have a look at this https://www.parse.com/questions/get-pfuser-in-pfquery-using-ios-api

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to load an image named "image1" or "default.png"?  Currently you're creating a variable named image1 with the value "default.png", but you're loading an image named "image1" because you quoted the name of your variable.

I assume that what you want is:

```
userpic.setImage(UIImage(named: "default.png"), forState: .Normal)
```

It's also worth noting that depending on how you store your images, you might need to omit the .png part of the name, so you may need to use:

```
userpic.setImage(UIImage(named: "default"), forState: .Normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

The image parameter is optional for `setImage` as given in the Apple docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setImage:forState:).

I think the problem lies with your initialization of `UIButton()`. Try setting a frame to the UIButton during initialization.

Tip: When it crashes, hover your mouse over `userpic` and `image` to see what data they contain. Useful feature in XCode that might help you find which object was unexpectedly found nil.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

Just you need to remove " self.userpic = UIButton() " this line and it's work .

you have already used @IBOutlet in storyboard with button . then you not need to do again self.userpic = UIButton() this line .

```
func getCurrentUserProfilePic(){

    let propicquery = PFUser.query
    propicquery()!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        var object = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId
        for object in objects!{
            let userPic = object["ProPic"] as! PFFile
            userPic.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if(error == nil){
                    let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                    self.userpic.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
                    self.userpic.addTarget(self, action: "userchange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
                    self.userpic.layer.cornerRadius = self.userpic.frame.size.width / 2;
                    self.userpic.clipsToBounds = true
                    self.view.addSubview(self.userpic)
                }

            })
        }
    }
}
```